# static variables lost values in JSP primefaces remoteCommand

Tags: java, javascript, primefaces

I implemented lazy loading data of freedays. When i use remoteCommand in moment when I need to load more data, my variable still haves init value. I even print the data in load func, it prints correctly, but after the func is finished value  is rolledback to old value from init without any msg or error. code:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named 
public class CalendarBean implements Serializable {
    private static String freeDays; //it should be static ?? without static the init func dont update there data. 

    public  String getFreeDays() {
         return freeDays;
    }

    public  void setFreeDays(String freeDayss) {
        this.freeDays= freeDayss;
    }

    public void loadDataFromDB(){
         freeDays=freeDays+//DB query with more data lazyloading
         ...
         System.out.print(freeDays); // it prints updated value with more object, but when the functions finish and I print CalendarBean.freeDays in Jscript it haves value from the init ...
    }

    public void initDays(){
         freeDays=//DB query
    }
}
```

.xhtml

```
<h:inputHidden id="hiddenButton2" value="#{CalendarBean.freeDays}"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="updateDaysJS" actionListener="#{CalendarBean.loadDataFromDB()}"/> //on default it is asynchronous i supose
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    #{CalendarBean.initDays()}
});
someFunction(){
    updateDaysJS();//this func triggered when i need more data of days
    //i ve tried also document.getElementById('MyForm:hiddenButton2').value = updateDaysJS(); but still not works(i ve changed ofc return type etc when i used this one
}
```

Comment: Try to make `freeDays` nonstatic and add `@PostConstruct` to `initDays` and additionally remove the jquery.ready-stuff.

Comment: i ve changed bean to ManagedBean SessionScoped vars to nonstatic, and in JS script i am using inputHidden components instead of call to bean variable. Now it works fine, anyway thx.